# JPA query compare timestamp with offset to system time

Tags: java, sql, jpa

I have few columns, among them two are

```
@Column(name = "time")
private Timestamp time = null;

@Column(name = "duration")
private long durationinMin = -1;
```

I have a requirement to  execute simple JPA query as **"select * from table where (time + durationinMin) <= SYSDATE"**.

Is there an easy way to do that?  We should be able to run it on all database servers.

Answer (score 0):

Using a JPA native query:

```
long t=time.getTime();
long m=durationinMin*60*1000;
Timestamp processedTimestamp = new Timestamp(t+m);

Query query = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM yourEntityTable WHERE ? <= SYSDATE", YourEntity.class);  
query.setParameter(1, processedTimestamp, TemporalType.TIMESTAMP);
List<YourEntity> resultsList = (List<YourEntity>) query.getResultList();
```

Comment: I am sorry if my question was not clear.  Time and durationinMin are the columns in the database.  JPA is not passing any param, it need to pull all records  whose (time + durationinMin) <= SYSDATE.

Comment: Uhm, I don't think it's possible to make a platform indipendent query (Sql Server has DATEADD, Oracle can add with a simple + etc etc.)

Answer (score 0):

JPQL only has limited operations for dates, basically get time, date, or datetime.

```
functions_returning_datetime:= CURRENT_DATE | CURRENT_TIME | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Reference: [10.2.5.16.3. JPQL Datetime Functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/kodo41/full/html/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_datetime).